# How can I check if adding noatime to /etc/fstab was effective?

Tags: mount, ssd, fstab

To prevent my SSD from unnecessary write accesses, I entered `noatime` under the mount options in `/etc/fstab` for the system and home partitions:

```
UUID=bla-bla-bla-1 /       ext4  errors=remount-ro,noatime 0 1
UUID=bla-bla-bla-2 /home   ext4  defaults,noatime          0 2
```

After that I rebooted.

Now I am surprised that the command

```
find . * -atime -0,01 -type f -printf "%TY-%Tm-%TdT%TT %p\n" | sort -r | ssed -R 's/^([^.]+)\.\d+ (.*)$/\1 \2/'
```

which I use occasionally to check which files have been accessed within the last approx. 1/4 hour, still works. On the one hand this is pleasing, but on the other hand I fear that `noatime` has not taken effect after all.

**How can I check this?**

Comment: Check what is mounted now, and how it is mounted with `mount|grep '^/dev'`

Comment: Thanks, great! It shows me `(rw,noatime,errors=remount-ro)
` for the first one and `(rw,noatime)` for my home partition! But how can my command show files by atime any longer?

Comment: I think the information is there, but it is not updated, which reduces the number of writes to the memory cells (which is important on pendrives and memory cards with cheap hardware with a low average number of writes to failure). Today new SSDs can stand a lot of writes, I don't think you need noatime on a modern SSD.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Type

```
mount | grep noatime
```

and will list all mountpoints with `noatime` in use. These 2 show `relatime` and you should see `noatime` next to your mountpoint.

```
sysfs on /sys type sysfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
proc on /proc type proc (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
```